# What is right way to sum up word2vec vectors generated by Gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I got four 300-dimention word2vec vectors like:

```
v1=model.wv.get_vector('A')
v2=model.wv.get_vector('B')
v3=model.wv.get_vector('C')
v4=model.wv.get_vector('D')
```

I want to compare cosine similarity of `v1+v2` and `v3+v4`.

Should I reduce them two 2-dimention vectors first or not?

What `numpy` function should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the vectors with simple Python math operators:

```
va = v1 + v2
vb = v3 + v4
```

`numpy` actually doesn't have a cosine-similarity (or cosine-distance) function, so you'd have to use the formula for calculating from the dot-product & unit-norm (both of which `numpy` has:

```
cossim = np.dot(va, vb) / (np.linalg.norm(va) * np.linalg.norm(vb))
```

Or, you could leverage the cosine-distance function in `scipy`, and convert it to cosine-similarity by subtracting it from 1:

```
cosdist = scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(va, vb)
cossim = 1 - cosdist
```